# Can someone give me a direction about using DNS to change location?

Tags: dns

I am in UK, I am planning to build a personal DNS server to use USA Netflix.

Can someone give me a direction how to use DNS to change my location from UK to US?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you use https://unlocator.com/? I'm curious how they are doing it personally, but would let you do it without reinventing the wheel...